# Searchview should filter only first 5 characters from a listview androidstudio

Tags: android-studio, filter, searchview

When i search it should only search first five characters from the array,

this is an app for finding dreams meaning, its like a dictionary app.

I added 2 listviews, and using a searchview to filter the results. but when i use searchview its searching the whole content in the array, and listing the result based on it which cause wrong results.

**if i could search only the first five characters from these arrays, it will help me to get right results.**

this is how i get the data from database

```
    listView2 = findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    sr_txt = findViewById(R.id.sr_txt);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("dreamapp");
    dream1 = new Dream();
    title_list = new ArrayList<>();
    answer_list = new ArrayList<>();


    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item, R.id.item, title_list);
    arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item2, R.id.item2, answer_list);
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot d : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                dream1 = d.getValue(Dream.class);
                title_list.add(dream1.getTitle());
                answer_list.add(dream1.getAnswer());
            }


            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            listView2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);


            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, answer.class);
                    //   String q = answer_list.get(i);
                    // String p =answer_list.get(i);
                    String q = (String) arrayAdapter2.getItem(i);
                    intent.putExtra("answer", q);

                    startActivity(intent);


                }

            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

this is my searchview.

```
  sr_txt.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter2.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter2.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please give any solution

Answer (score 0):

Please give more detail of what you want.It would be more clear if you dont mind uploading image of what you are getting and what you want.

Comment: the problem is the app is in my mother tongue,  so if i even uploaded it, it wont make any sense , its an app for showing the dreams meaning , its same as a dictionary app, its having a list of objects and when you click on it , it shows meaning of that, the problem when i search it searches the whole content in the array , i only wanted to search first five characters from the array.